# Child component doesn't update on parent request ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, components

Have looked at other similar questions to this, but i can't find one that looks relevant to this.

I basically have a blog section on a website, and the article list page is using pagination. Every time pagination is called, it requests the next 10 blog articles form the backed. All works absolutely fine, apart from one minor bug that i can't figure out. Within the .map loop within the return, i'm outputting along with the title, link etc the author. I get the Author ID from the CMS backend, and i'm using a component to deliver the author image back (passing props). This works fine on initial load, but never changes even when called again.

Here's snippets of my code that's relevant;

Articles.js

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            posts: [],
            type: null,
            totalResults: 0,
            pageCount: 0,
            currentPage: 1,
            perPage: 9,
            limit: 9,
            offset: 0,
        }

        this.getPosts = this.getPosts.bind(this);
        this.toggleType = this.toggleType.bind(this);
    }



    componentDidMount(){
        this.loadAPI();
        this.loadAPI(true);
    }

getPosts(){
        if(this.state.posts.length){
            return this.state.posts.map((content,index) => {
                var url = content.Title.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
                url = url.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
                        let bkgrdimg = `url(http://**.**.**.***${content.articleImage.url})`;
                    return(
                        <Col md={4} className="mb-4" key={index}>
                            <VisibilitySensor partialVisibility={'top'} offset={{ top: -550 }} minTopValue="30"> 
                            {({isVisible}) => 
                            <Card className={`animated ${isVisible ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut'}`}>
                                <Link to={{ pathname: `/posts/${url}`,state: {content} }} style={{overflow: 'hidden'}}>
                                    { content.articleImage !=null ?

                                    <Card.Img variant="top" alt={content.Title} src={"http://**.**.**.***"+content.articleImage.url} />

                                </Link>
                                <Card.Body>
                                    <Link to={{ pathname: `/posts/${url}` }}>
                                        <Card.Title>{this.truncateOnWord(content.Title,50)}</Card.Title>
                                    </Link>
                                    <Card.Text>{this.truncateOnWord(content.SEOMetaDescription,150)}</Card.Text>
                                </Card.Body>
                                <Card.Footer>
                                    <Portrait displayFromAPIID={content.Author._id} displayProfile="false" publishedDate={<Moment format="MMM DD, YYYY">{content.DatePublished}</Moment>}></Portrait> 
                                </Card.Footer>
                            </Card>
                            } 
                            </VisibilitySensor>
                        </Col>
                    );
            })
        }



    }

handlePageClick = data => {
        var myElement = document.getElementById('articles');
        var topPos = myElement.offsetTop;
        window.scrollTo({top: topPos, behavior: 'smooth'});

        var selected = data.selected +1;
        var offset = ((selected * this.state.perPage) - this.state.perPage);
        var limit = (this.state.perPage * selected);

        this.setState({ offset: offset, limit: limit }, () => {
          this.loadAPI();
        });
    };

    render() {
            return (
                <div>
                        <Row>
                            <CardDeck>
                                {this.getPosts()}
                            </CardDeck>
                        </Row>
                        <div >
                        <ReactPaginate
                            previousLabel='&laquo;'
                            previousClassName={ 'previousBtn'}
                            nextLabel='&raquo;'
                            nextClassName={'nextBtn'}        
                            breakLabel={'...'}
                            breakClassName={'break-me'}
                            activeClassName={'active'}
                            pageClassName={'page-item'}
                            pageLinkClassName={'page-link'}
                            containerClassName={'pagination'}
                            subContainerClassName={'pages pagination'}
                            pageCount={this.state.pageCount}
                            marginPagesDisplayed={2}
                            pageRangeDisplayed={5}
                            onPageChange={this.handlePageClick}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
```

You can see in the getPosts() function in the map loop see use the  component - this is what is not being updated on request.

Portrait component.js

```
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = {
                staffToDisplay: this.props.staffToDisplay,
                imageSrc: null,
                imageSrcHover: null,
                name: null,
                role: null,
                bio: null,
                skillset: [],
                apiID: null,
                profileInDetail: this.props.profileInDetail,
                displayProfile: this.props.displayProfile,
                displayFromAPIID: this.props.displayFromAPIID,
                publishedDate: this.props.publishedDate,
                show: false,
                hover: false,
                linkToPage: this.props.linkToPage,
            }
            this.handleModal = this.handleModal.bind(this);
            this.selectStaffMembers = this.selectStaffMembers.bind(this);
            this.toggleHover = this.toggleHover.bind(this);

        }

        componentDidMount() {
            this.selectStaffMembers();
            this.setState({displayFromAPIID: this.props.displayFromAPIID});
        }

        componentDidUpdate() {
        }

selectStaffMembers() {

        //List all staff members
        const portraits = [
            { 
                'objName': imgOneObject, 
                'role': 'Job Title',
                'name': 'Raul Duke',
                'bio': 'this is a bio',
                'skillset': ['blah','blah','blah','blah'],
                'imgSwap': imgOneObjectAltVersion, 
                'apiID': '5d84***',
                'linkedin' : 'https://...',
            },
            { 
             ...
             ...
             ...
            },
        ];

        //Get corresponding portrait for this instance
        for (var i = 0; i < portraits.length; i++) {
            if (this.state.staffToDisplay){
                if (this.state.staffToDisplay === Object.keys(portraits[i])[0]) {
                    this.setState({
                        imageSrc: Object.values(portraits[i])[0],
                        name: Object.values(portraits[i])[2],
                        role: Object.values(portraits[i])[1],
                        bio: Object.values(portraits[i])[3],
                        skillset: Object.values(portraits[i])[4],
                        imageSrcHover: Object.values(portraits[i])[5],
                        apiID: Object.values(portraits[i])[6],
                        linkedin: Object.values(portraits[i])[7],
                    })
                }
            }
            if (this.state.displayFromAPIID){
                if(this.state.displayFromAPIID === Object.values(portraits[i])[6]){
                    this.setState({
                        imageSrc: Object.values(portraits[i])[0],
                        name: Object.values(portraits[i])[2],
                        role: Object.values(portraits[i])[1],
                        bio: Object.values(portraits[i])[3],
                        skillset: Object.values(portraits[i])[4],
                        imageSrcHover: Object.values(portraits[i])[5],
                        apiID: Object.values(portraits[i])[6],
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }

    getPortraitImg(){
            var profile = ""
                profile = <p className="mt-3">{this.state.name}<br/>{this.state.publishedDate}</p>                      

            return(
                <Row className="showAuthor">
                    <Col lg={4}>
                        <img className="profileImg img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src={this.state.imageSrc} alt={this.state.name}></img>
                    </Col>
                    <Col lg={8}>
                        { profile }
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            )
        }

    render() {
            const portrait_img = this.getPortraitImg();
                return (
                    <div>
                        {portrait_img}
                    </div>
                );
        }
```

I thought it was because the function selectStaffMembers() was onMount, but if i put it in componentDidUpdate() it just errors out.

Can anyone see where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Could you please add a codepen. That'll help us understand what's happening, more clearly.

Comment: Ok, will add it to code pen shortly